# How to build an ISO of customized linux OS in a way that I can use the ISO to install on other systems?

Tags: linux

I have installed minimal version of centos6.7 on usb stick, copied/installed some applications/packages and customized accordingly.

Now I want to build an ISO of my customized OS and want to install on other systems using ISO.

Is that possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: tar up your install, and put a copy on a USB stick with gparted or systemrescuecd etc on it.  partition and format the target system's disk, mount the freshly formatted partitions,  and untar your tar archive onto it.  chroot into the target mount and run `install-grub /dev/sdX` (where /dev/sdX is the device name of the target system's boot disk)

Comment: Thank you cas for replying. As I said before, somehow I want to make an ISO so that I can share with remote team and they can install on their systems. Locally I can just do the 'dd' of the installed usb to the new usb(and it worked for me).

Comment: no problem. i'm not able to type up a detailed answer right now, so just posted a comment to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Since you're using CentOS/Redhat, consider using kickstart if your aim is a (mostly) unattended install on indeterminate systems.

Comment: Do you just want to install the same software or do you want to include data and settings (e.g. some documents (data) and a changed UI theme (settings))?

Comment: When you installed CentOS, it wrote a file "/root/anaconda-ks.cfg". If you use that file for a qiuickstart it will install identically everywhere else. If you transfer a kickstart to another computer, it might not install because of different hardware. Therefore, documentation is your friend https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/s1-kickstart2-options. You can make quite amazing self installing (unattended) procedures, and you can write your own custom scripts executed before of after installation.

Comment: A graphic kickstart configurator is also an attractive option. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/ch-redhat-config-kickstart

Answer (score 0):

Unlike, say, Microsoft Windows, there's nothing magical or special about any files on the filesystem, the system won't break if they're in a different sector of the disk from when the system was first installed.  That means you can just do a file copy of the entire filesystem from one disk to another and it will Just Work.

Knowing this, you can:

- `tar cfxz mysystem.tar.gz /`

If /boot, /home, /usr, or /var are on separate file-systems, you need to list them on the tar command line.  the `-x` option prevents descent into mounted filesystems to exclude `/proc`, and `/sys`.  e.g. if they are all separately mounted filesystems:

`tar cfxz mysystem.tar.gz / /boot /home /usr /var`

adjust to suit your install.

- create a USB stick containing `gparted`
- mount it
- copy `mysystem.tar.gz` to it.
- unmount it.
- send the USB stick (or a copy of it) to whoever needs to install it, with instructions to:

  1. boot it
  2. use gparted to create the partitions (rootfs, swap, any others)
  3. bring up a root shell
  4. mount the partitions under /target.  e.g. if you have / and /boot on /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2:

  `mkdir -p /target
  mount /dev/sda1 /target
  mkdir -p /target/boot
  mount /dev/sda2 /boot`

  5. extract `mysystem.tar.gz` onto `/target`:

  `tar xfz /mysystem.tar.gz -C /target`

  6. edit `/target/etc/fstab` as necessary so that it matches the filesystems on this new system.
  7. if `/target/etc/udev/rules/70-persistent-net.rules` exists, delete it.
  8. prepare for chrooting into /target in order to run `grub-install`:

  `for i in proc dev sys dev/pts ; do mount -o bind /$i /target/$i ; done`

  9. `chroot /target`
  10. `install-grub /dev/sda`
  11. `exit`
  12. `for i in proc dev sys dev/pts boot /; do umount /target/$i ; done`
  13. reboot. your system should be cloned onto the new disk.

This method works just as well if you create a bootable CD or DVD containing both `gparted` and a copy of `mysystem.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dd` to make the iso:

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/new/iso.iso`

(Changing the `if` (input file) and `of` (output file) accordingly.)

And to install it to every disk you want to install it on:

`sudo dd if=/path/to/iso.iso of=/dev/sdb`

(Changing the `if` (input file) and `of` (output file) accordingly.)